# which hook is effective for setting custom breadcrumbs?

Tags: 7, theming, breadcrumbs

I have a theme which sets breadcrumbs like this:

```
function mytheme_process_node(&$variables) {
    (....)
    drupal_set_breadcrumb($my_breadcrumbs_array);
}
```

This gets overwritten later by something else. I need a specific taxonomy value of the displayed node to set the breadcrumb, that's why I am using this hook. How to do it effectively? Perhaps there is a hook which is performed later and still has access to the node object?

Comment: "a specific taxonomy value" - that is, a specific taxonomy term reference field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I normally stick that logic in `hook_preprocess_page()`, it runs late enough in the page build to not be overwritten by anything else.

You can still get access to the node object by using the [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) function:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    // We're on a node page...
    drupal_set_breadcrumb($my_breadcrumbs_array);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also [hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter/7)

Besides, you can use one of the plenty of [breadcrumb-customizing modules](https://drupal.org/node/533448) and *might* get what you want without custom code.

Comment: It is tempting to use this hook but you may end up with a correct breadcrumb and a wrong menu active trail.